# How to create a Java Map<String,String> with unmodifiable keys?

Tags: java, string, dictionary, keyvaluepair, unmodifiable

**In java, how should I create a `Map<String,String>` that has unmodifiable keys, while keeping the values modifiable.**

I'd like to hand this `Map<String,String>` through an interface for someone else to add/change the Map values, but not be able to change the Map keys.

The background on higher level problem is that I have list/set of variable names (with tree like structure) (represented as java String) that I'd like code on the other side of the java interface to be able to populate aliases (also Strings) for each of the variable names. I'd like to have multiple implementations of this interface so naming tree hierarchy can be aliases different ways to fit different situations. Having the interface implementation populate a `Map<String,String>` with bunch of keys already set-in-stone (and maybe containing defaults for the values) and allowing it to modify the values (but not the keys), seems like the best approach. I'm creating a mapping between names and alias, so `Map<>` makes sense.

Back to the lower level problem. I'd like my code to resemble:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public interface IMyMapper
        {
            void build(Map<String,String> mapping);
        }

        IMyMapper mapper;

        // How I'd like to use it
        void work()
        {
            Map<String,String> map ;
            // Magic something like Collections unmodifiableMap, but only for keys
            // Maybe my question should be how this magic for UnmodifiableMap works, so I could reproduce it??
            mapper.build(map); 
            // Because Maps<> are by reference, changed they made (to the values) would be reflected here
        }
    }

    public class TheirClass implements MyClass.IMyMapper
    {
        @Override
        public void build(Map<String,String> mapping)
        {
            // use mapping like Map<String,String> without extra/foreign classes
            // but not be able to modify the Map keys
            // only be able to change the Map values
            // Should be able to use all of the awesome Map stuff, like foreach, values, compute
        }
    }
```

I know there is `Collections unmodifiableMap(Map<> m)` but that also makes the values unmodifiable. If my values were mutable objects, then I could modify them but I'd like to stick with `Strings` (avoiding creating Class with set/get for single String member, or creating Structure-like-class with public String member).

AKA, I'd like to avoid creating my own mutable class-values, and use `Collections unmodifiableMap()` to make the keys and `value references` unmodifiable:

```
    // mutable reference to a String
    public class ExtraWorkForForEveryone
    {
        public String value;

        public void setValue(String value) { ... }
        public String getValue() { ... }
    }

    // and then use:
    void work()
    {            
        Map<String,ExtraWorkForEveryone> map;
        map = Collections.unmodifiableMap( ... );
        // because Collections.unmodifiableMap() only stops them from changing the Map references,
        // the interfacer could still change the ExtraWorkForEveryone internals.
        // so they could not change keys refs or value refs, but they could change value data.
        mapper.build(map); 
        // Because Maps<> are by reference, changed they made (to the values) would be reflected here
    }
```

I could extend or implement my own Map, then (like how `Collections unmodifiableMap()`) override all methods that could change the keys throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. But with Java 8, there has been a large number of methods added using Lambda functions, which would be nice for Interface implementers to have access to, as long as they could not change the keys.

AKA, I'd like to avoid this lengthy and error-prone technique:

```
    public final class FinalHashMap extends HashMap
    {
        @Override // anything that might be able to change the Map Keys
        so_many_methods_and_edge_cases()
        { throws UnsupportedOperationException }
    }
```

Is there existing interface that only allows changing the data of values of `Maps<>`?

What are my other options for creating something resembling a `Map<String,String>` that has **unmodifiable keys**, but **modifiable values**? I am interested in good coding practices, if possible.

Comment: So you want to be able to do `put(existingKey, otherValue)`, but not `put(newKey, someValue)`?

Comment: How is this any different than using a standard Map?

Comment: Wrap the map and don't provide the remove() the method.

Comment: Would you like to detect the abuse immediately or afterwards? If it's ok to do it afterwards and reject the abuse, you can simply pass a copy to the interface and then compare the key sets after the invocation. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for the [Proxy Pattern](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).

---

Detailed answer:

The idea is to use what's called a *proxy* to interact with the map. The proxy will intercept all calls to the map; you should only be able to interact with the map through the proxy. It acts as an interface between the client and the map.

A proxy is a skeleton of what you are "wrapping". Since you are creating a proxy for a map, the proxy should implement the `Map` interface:

```
class ImmutableMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {
    private Map<K, V> map;

    public ImmutableMap(Map<K, V> map) {
        this.map = new HashMap<>(map); // detach reference
    }

    //implement methods from Map
}
```

Most methods will simply telescope to `map`. Modify the methods you need to prevent removing keys or adding new keys to the map, such as `put`, `putAll` and `remove`:

```
final class ImmutableMap<K, V> implementsMap<K, V> {
    private Map<K, V> map;

    public ImmutableMap(Map<K, V> map) {
        this.map = new HashMap<>(map);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return map.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return map.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return map.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return map.containsValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        if(!map.containsKey(key)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot add new keys!");
        }

        return map.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You cannot remove entries from this map!");
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map) {
        for(K key : map.keySet()) {
            if(!this.map.containsKey(key)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot add new keys to this map!");
            }
        }

        this.map.putAll(map);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You cannot remove entries from this map!");
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(map.keySet());
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(map.values()); //prevebt changing values to null
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        //to allow modification of values, create your own ("immutable") entry set and return that
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(map.entrySet()); 
    }
}
```

Keynotes:

1. `Collections.unmodifiableSet` should be used when returning sets from the map. This ensures that if a person attempts to modify a set returned from the map, it'll throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`
2. Creating a new `Map` containing the values of the map passed into the constructor prevents the client from modifying the `ImmutableMap` using the map they passed into it.

Comment: Now that I see your answer, his question makes more sense.

Comment: `Map` is an interface, so `s/extends/implements/`

Comment: I would implement the interface and have an internal map so that my class acts as a proxy to the real map.

Comment: `if(get(key) == null)` what if `value` I `put` will be `null`? With this approach I will not be able to change it later. IMO it is better to have some separate `Set` of keys and when we try to put some element check if key is present in this set.

Comment: But Do all of the other fancy Map methods (like forEach/values/compute/Iterable/keySet/replaceAll/etc) solely rely on remove & put methods (for changing/adding/deleting keys)?
Or will I need to go through each of them to figure out which could possible modify keys? That results in the problem that a lot of the nice methods like forEach provide alternate Iterators that could allow changing of the keys.

Comment: @abaines: Not necessarily, which is why you might be better off extending `AbstractMap` and wrapping a field of type `HashMap`.

Comment: The sample implementation is also not threadsafe, but it is just an example.

Comment: Maybe [ForwardingMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMap.html) from Guava might be useful as a base for decorating a real map.

Comment: Wow! I pretty much did the same thing as you Vince, except few questions:

Shouldn't the constructor be this.map = new HashMap<>(map) so that references to argument map cannot modify this.map?

I would think entrySet() would return Collections.unmodifiableSet(map.entrySet()); instead of a copy?

Similarly, wouldn't keySet() return Collections.unmodifiableSet(map.keySet()); ?

Comment: @VinceEmigh Looking at implementation of HashMap, it looks like you could to pre-check for putAll(Map<> m) and make that valid in cases where no new keys were introduced.
  
Also, what is verdict on returning Collections.unmodifiableSet(...) for entrySet() and keySet() instead of  copies?

Comment: @VinceEmigh with copy, someone could change the copy thinking they were changing the real thing, but with UnmodifiableSet if they tried to change it, they would get error. Correct?

Comment: @abaines Exactly. I was more focused on introducing the aspect of modifying the functionality of a type to achieve what you want. I just noticed your note about good practices, so I'll edit my answer to fit

Answer (score 0):

you may want to limit the size of your map

In over riding your put method you may use

```
if (map.size() == maxEntries) {
             throw some exception;
```